# How do I show original image size in modal?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an app where images are drawn up on pages at screen width or less, but if I click them, I open a modal to show the image at full size. It works fine on ios but for some reason Android doesn't show the original image, but a much smaller sized image. I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't show the original image from url. I'm using a template for my modal:

```
<ScrollView #imgScroll orientation="horizontal">
        <Image [src]="img" (loaded)="onImageLoaded($event);" (pinch)="onPinch($event)" #dragImage class="largeImage" stretch="none"></Image>
    </ScrollView>
```

Then in my code, I'm setting the scroller and allowing the user to be able to drag the image around to inspect the entire image.

```
onImageLoaded(args: EventData){
    let dragImage = <Image>args.object;
    if(dragImage){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.imgSize = dragImage.getActualSize();
            if(this.imgSize.width>this.imgSize.height){
                this.orientation = "landscape";
                this.imageScroller.scrollToHorizontalOffset(this.imgSize.width / 4, true);

            } else {
                this.orientation = "portrait";
                this.imageScroller.scrollToVerticalOffset(this.imgSize.width / 4, true);
            }
            console.log("Image Size: ", this.imgSize);
        },1500);
    }   
}

onImagePan(args: PanGestureEventData){
    if (args.state === 1){
    this.prevX = 0
    this.prevY = 0;
    }
    if (args.state === 2) // panning
    {
        this.dragImageItem.translateX += args.deltaX - this.prevX;
        this.dragImageItem.translateY += args.deltaY - this.prevY;
        this.prevX = args.deltaX;
        this.prevY = args.deltaY;
    } else if (args.state === 3){
        this.dragImageItem.animate({
            translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            duration: 1000,
            curve: AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
          });      
    }
}

onPinch(args: PinchGestureEventData) {
    console.log("Pinch scale: " + args.scale + " state: " + args.state);
    if(this.imgSize){
        if (args.state === 1) {
            var newOriginX = args.getFocusX() - this.dragImageItem.translateX;
            var newOriginY = args.getFocusY() - this.dragImageItem.translateY;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what gets logged to the console:

```
Image Size:  {
    "width": 533.3333333333334,
    "height": 127.33333333333333
}
```

The actual image dimensions are 900 x 600.

It sort of appears Android is caching the image from the page and not showing the actual image from the url. I don't get why iOS works but Android does not. Anyone have any ideas?

Version: 1.17.0-v.2019.5.31.1 (latest)
NativeScript CLI version: 5.4.2
CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.17.6
CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing device independent pixels with actual pixels.

[getActualSize()](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#getactualsize) returns width and height in DPI format, use [utils.layout. toDevicePixels(getActualSize().width) Or utils.layout. toDevicePixels(getActualSize().height)](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_utils_utils_.layout#todevicepixels) to get actual pixel value.

Comment: Ok, but why isn’t the image loading in full size to begin with?

Comment: It works perfectly on my end, I was able to see the entire image and it was scrollable as expected. If you have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: what does useCache="false" do? I get this: ERROR  ERROR Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT).=======Check the 'adb logcat' for additional information about the error.=======

Comment: Here is my playground. Tap the image. Works fine on iOS. Errors on Android. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XqM1hK&v=17

Comment: Your Playground itself is broken, are you sure you attached latest.

Comment: Hmm, here is what it looks like on my iPhone in the Playground: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDOb2S9xgmbNi2UIVG9t__KKTh9-mfxT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this one work better? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XqM1hK&v=18

Comment: The first page works, the modal page is where you are saying the image is not show at it's full width / height right? Tapping on the image (which should open modal page), simply fails with exception.

Comment: Yes, but not on ios. And in my app it does not throw exception, but opens with the cached image from the page.

Comment: Your code has numerous issues, you have attribute binding on decodedWidth, decodedHeight, orientation etc., on template but you are not assigning initial values until image is loaded. Decoded width / height are specific to Android, since you haven't set any value (undefined) its crashing. Also there is no use in setting decoded width / height after you set src property, you are setting src value (img) in constructor. Here is ugly fix I used - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XqM1hK&v=19

Comment: Thanks for your work on this. Should I just remove the decodeWidth and decodeHeight altogether? I noticed you set the timeout to 5000 on adding the scroller settings.

Comment: As I mentioned it was a ugly quick fix just to show you what all were the issue. If you remove decoded width or height completely it will be default to screen width / height. You must set width / height to image's width or height. If you are sure you will get the width and height form the URL itself, you could use that.